# Widgets not displaying in Scroll Area

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created two .ui files using pyqt designer: one being a Main Window and another being a Widget. Whenever I try to add a widget to the scroll area in my Main Window, it doesn't display on the screen and i can't figure out why.

Sorry if it's a stupid question, i'm still learning pyqt5 and pyqt designer. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

CODE:

```
   class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window,self).__init__()
            self.ui=Ui_Reddit()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
            #self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)
            self.setWindowTitle("Reddit")
            self.show()
            self.mainWindow()

        def mainWindow(self):
            #to handle all the api calls using praw
            self.x = RedditApi()
            self.printSubmissions()

        def printSubmissions(self):
            #Gets the list of all submission titles to be displayed
            #TO DO: Get and add other things like points and comments

            self.submissions = self.x.showSubmissions()

            for submission in self.submissions:

                card = QWidget()
                card_ui = Ui_Card()
                card_ui.setupUi(card)
                card_ui.title.setText(submission)
                self.ui.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(card)
```

Ui_Reddit:

```
class Ui_Reddit(object):
    def setupUi(self, Reddit):
        Reddit.setObjectName("Reddit")
        Reddit.resize(800, 600)
        Reddit.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Reddit)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 781, 531))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 779, 
        529))

     self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = 
        QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 811, 
        551))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = 
        QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = 
        QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setIndent(5)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.search_bar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.search_bar.setText("")
        self.search_bar.setObjectName("search_bar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.search_bar)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        Reddit.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Reddit)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Reddit.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Reddit)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Reddit)

    def retranslateUi(self, Reddit):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Reddit.setWindowTitle(_translate("Reddit", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Reddit", "TextLabel"))
        self.search_bar.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Reddit", "Search"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Reddit", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Reddit = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Reddit()
    ui.setupUi(Reddit)
    Reddit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui_Card:

```
class Ui_Card(object):
    def setupUi(self, Card):
        Card.setObjectName("Card")
        Card.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Card.setEnabled(True)
        Card.resize(771, 134)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Card.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Card.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel(Card)
        self.title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 10, 761, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.title.setFont(font)
        self.title.setObjectName("title")
        self.user = QtWidgets.QLabel(Card)
        self.user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 47, 13))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.user.setFont(font)
        self.user.setObjectName("user")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Card)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 20, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.subreddit = QtWidgets.QLabel(Card)
        self.subreddit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 47, 13))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.subreddit.setFont(font)
        self.subreddit.setObjectName("subreddit")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Card)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 771, 
        31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = 
        QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.comments = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.comments.setObjectName("comments")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comments)
        self.upvote = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.upvote.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("upvoteArrow.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, 
        QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.upvote.setIcon(icon)
        self.upvote.setFlat(True)
        self.upvote.setObjectName("upvote")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.upvote)
        self.downvote = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.downvote.setFlat(True)
        self.downvote.setObjectName("downvote")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.downvote)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Card)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 771, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")

        self.retranslateUi(Card)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Card)

    def retranslateUi(self, Card):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Card.setWindowTitle(_translate("Card", "Form"))
        self.title.setText(_translate("Card", "TextLabel"))
        self.user.setText(_translate("Card", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Card", "-"))
        self.subreddit.setText(_translate("Card", "TextLabel"))
        self.comments.setText(_translate("Card", "TextLabel"))
        self.downvote.setText(_translate("Card", "downvote"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Card = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Card()
    ui.setupUi(Card)
    Card.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share `Ui_Reddit` and `Ui_Card` or .uis

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry for the delay. I've updated the post.